# Foreach does not work while using json in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, foreach

,Hi all,

I am trying to use json.İf ı return to partial view ,i can not use foreach for my customer session.My Customer Session has customers.I can not list them.
Where i miss ?

```
CONTROLLER:

public ActionResult ShowResult(MyModel model)
{
Session["CustomerList"] = context.Customer.Where(s => s.CustomerSituation== true).ToList(); // Customers List To Session
var stringView = RenderRazorViewToString("_ShowResultPartial", model);
return Json(stringView, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

.

```
My _ShowResultPartial View:
@foreach (var item in (List<Q502351.Models.Customer>)Session["CustomerList"])
{
Ajax.ActionLink(item.CustomerName, "ShowResult", new { CustomerId = item.CustomerId}, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have posted, it's not clear why you want to store the customer list in session; data for the view should generally be stored on the view model.  Even if you have a compelling reason to use session, it's a better practice to retrieve the session variables in the controller and store them in the view model.  Then you should be able to loop through the list on the model from the view.  In this situation it doesn't look like session is necessary at all (unless you intend to reuse the stored data later and for some reason cannot pass it along via models).

Also, unless there is a good reason to return json, your ShowResult controller method should just return a PartialView.

Something like this should work...

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ShowResult(MyModel model)
{
    model.Customers = context.Customer.Where(s => s.CustomerSituation == true).ToList();
    return PartialView("_ShowResultPartial"), model);
}
```

Partial view:

```
@model MyModel

@foreach (var item in Model.Customers)
{
    Ajax.ActionLink(item.CustomerName, "ShowResult", new { CustomerId = item.CustomerId}, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" });
}
```